# optima of a random function / stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, optimization, stochastic-processes, random-functions, risk-assessment

Consider the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, and let $X:\Omega \mapsto \mathbb{R}^T$, where $T$ is an index set, be a random function.
What is the canonical definition of the optima of $X$?

The simplest I could think of is
$$\mathrm{optima}(X) := \mathrm{optima}\left(t \mapsto \mathbb{E}[X(t)]\right).$$
However, this definition ignores all the  randomness in $X$. I'd instead want the definition to satisfy something like the following

> If $t_1$ and $t_2$ are two candidate optima such that $\mathbb{E}[X(t_1)] = \mathbb{E}[X(t_2)]$ and $\mathbb{Var}[X(t_1)] < \mathbb{Var}[X(t_2)]$, then $t_1$ is a better choice than $t_2$.

and

> If $t_1$ and $t_2$ are two candidate optima such that $\mathbb{Var}[X(t_1)] = \mathbb{Var}[X(t_2)]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X(t_1)] > \mathbb{E}[X(t_2)]$, then $t_1$ is a better choice than $t_2$.

which is to say that I prefer points with higher certainty. To this end, I could for example define
$$\mathrm{optima}(X) := \mathrm{optima}\left(t \mapsto \frac{\mathbb{E}[X(t)]}{\sqrt{\mathbb{Var}[X(t)]}} \right),$$
or
$$\mathrm{optima}(X) := \mathrm{optima}\left(t \mapsto \mathbb{E}[X(t)] - \sqrt{\mathbb{Var}[X(t)]} \right).$$

But these seem contrived. I suspect there are other better/standard definitions in common use, that I just haven't come across.

For a concrete example, one may use $$X_t = t(1-t) + B_t, \quad t \in [0,1]$$
where $B_t$ is standard Brownian motion, and define its maxima. By the first definition above, the maxima is $\dfrac{1}{2}$, where as by the second it is $\dfrac{1}{3}$.

Some references I've found:

- [***Risk Averse Optimization*** chapter from *Lectures on Stochastic Programming* by Andrzej Ruszczyński and Alexander Shapiro](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1.9780898718751.ch6)
- [***Optimization Under Uncertainty*** lecture notes by R. T. Rockafellar, University of Washington](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ertr/uncertainty.pdf)
- [***Risk Averse Control*** lecture note by Sanjay Lall, Stanford University](http://ee266.stanford.edu/lectures/risk_averse.pdf)

Comment: In your first definition theres no time dependence, do you take infimum over $t\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Edited the first definition to show the time dependence.

Comment: You could also ask for $\mathbb{E}[\inf_{t}X(t)]$, or $\mathbb{E}[\text{argmin}_{t}X(t)]$

Comment: @DanielAdams That's interesting. Any idea how to compute it for the example?

Comment: No its much harder, just examples of things you could call "optima of $X(t)$".

Comment: Arn't you concerned that in constructing your second definition you may choose a $t$ as optimal but there may exists a $\tilde{t}$ such that $\mathbb{E}[X(\tilde{t})]< \mathbb{E}[X(t)]$ ? I guess its just a trade off between how far you want to be from the true optimum and how sure you want to be that you will hit that optimum.

Comment: You are spot on: it's the trade off. But I'm not sure what is the "correct" trade off.

Comment: I guess neither depends on what you want :)